# List has no rows for assignment to SObject I faced This error when I used action suport function

Tags: lightning-aura-components

--This My Apex Code--

```
public class inqueryobject {
    Public List<Inquiry__c> listinq{set;get;}
    Public Inquiry__c inqs{set;get;}

    Public inqueryobject(apexpages.StandardController controller){
        inqs=new Inquiry__c();       
        listinq=new List<Inquiry__c>();
        Addproduct();
    }
Public void Addproduct(){
    Inquiry__c inq=new Inquiry__c();
    listinq.add(inq);

}
Public void RemoveRow(){
    integer row=integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('del'));
    if(row>1){
        listinq.remove(row-1);
    }

}
Public pagereference Save(){
    upsert listinq;
    pagereference pr=new pagereference('/apex/inqueryobjectvfpage');
    return pr;
}
Public void ContactInfo(){

    Contact con=[select id,MailingStreet,MailingCity,MailingState,MailingPostalCode,MailingCountry from Contact
                where id=:inqs.Contact_Name__c limit 1];

       Inqs.Street__c         = Con.MailingStreet;
   Inqs.City__c           = Con.MailingCity;                    
   Inqs.State_Province__c = Con.MailingState;
   Inqs.Zip_Postal_Code__c= Con.MailingPostalCode; 
   Inqs.Country__c        = Con.MailingCountry ;                     
      listinq.add(inqs);         


    }

}
```

--This My Vf Code----

```
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Contact Name" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Contact_Name__c}" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ContactInfo}" />
             </apex:inputField>

        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Inquiry Date and Time" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Inquiry_Date_and_Time__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Expectations" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Expectations__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Inquiry Source" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Inquiry_Source__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Mode of Delivery" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Mode_of_Delivery__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Order Status" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Order_Status__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Shipment Date" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Shipment_Date__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Approval Status" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Approval_Status__c}" />
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column headerValue="Add" >
            <apex:commandLink value="Add" action="{!Addproduct}" reRender="panel" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Remove" >
            <apex:commandLink value="remove" action="{!RemoveRow}" reRender="panel" >
                <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="del" />
            </apex:commandLink>
           <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}" />
        </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Address Information">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listinq}" var="inq">
        <apex:column headerValue="street" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Street__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="City" > 
            <apex:inputField value="{!inq.City__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="State/Province" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!inq.State_Province__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Zip/Postal Code" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Zip_Postal_Code__c}" />
        </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Country" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!inq.Country__c}" />
        </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should simply make sure that Id is not null before you try to do the query:

```
public void ContactInfo(){
  if(inqs.Contact_Name__c == null) {
    return; // No record selected
  }
  // ... do query here
}
```

In the general case, when you're not querying by an Id, you should first query in to a list, and select the first item if the list is not empty.

```
SObject[] records = [select ... from ... where ... limit 1];
if(records.size() == 1) {
  // Do something with records[0]
```

Alternatively, you may choose to try-catch a QueryException:

```
try {
  SObject record = [select ... from ... where ... limit 1];
  // Do something with record
} catch(QueryException e) {
  // No record was found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Contact con=[select id,MailingStreet,MailingCity,MailingState,MailingPostalCode,MailingCountry from Contact
            where id=:inqs.Contact_Name__c limit 1];
```

Instead of using this we should use like that

```
Public void ContactInfo(){

    List<Contact> conList =[select id,MailingStreet,MailingCity,MailingState,MailingPostalCode,MailingCountry from Contact
                where id=:inqs.Contact_Name__c limit 1];

    if(conList.size() > 0){

       Contact con = conList[0];
       // Your logic . . . 
    }
}
```

**Note: Now this will give you an error if no record is returned. So to overcome this what we can do is, create a list of Contact**